# Need to disable more that 10 Fields in Openerp

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I have created a new module and added 10 fields to it.Now i should be able to enter only 5 fields first and on payment i should be able to enter next 5 fields.Can anyone please help me.

I want my sales person to enter only Basic Details first(like Name and Address and Phone number) and later after payment i want to update Full details of Parents and their Contact info.
thank's in advance

My code is

lead_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<!-- ===================== This is tree layout =============================-->
<record id="lead_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Lead</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="lead">
                <field name = "name"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

<!-- ========================This is Form layout===============================-->
    <record id="view_res_partner_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view.res.partner.inherited</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
                <field name="website" position="replace"/>
                <field name="title" position="replace"/>
                <field name="function" position="replace"/>
                <field name="category_id" position="replace"/>
                <page string="Internal Notes" position="before">
                    <page string="Contract">
                        <group>
                            <group>
                                <h3>Contract Details</h3><br/>
                                <field name="storagedetails"/>
                                <field name="insurancecompany"/>
                                <field name="insurancenumber"/>
                                <field name="healthfund_name"/>
                                <field name="healthfund_number"/>
                                <field name="service"/>
                                <field name="annualfee"/>
                                <field name="paymentplan"/>
                                <field name="transport_insurance"/>
                                <field name="sarm"/>
                                <field name="cost_free_donation"/>
                                <field name="hla_test"/>
                                <field name="twins"/>
                                <field name="repeated_customer"/>
                            </group>
                            <group>
                                <h3>Relevant Dates</h3><br/>
                                <field name="contactadded_date"/>
                                <field name="clientadded_date"/>
                                <field name="expectedbirth_date"/>
                                <field name="bloodrecieved_date"/>
                                <field name="bloodstorage_date"/>
                                <field name="cordrecieved_date"/>
                                <field name="cordstored_date"/>
                                <br/><br/>
                                <h3>End Contract</h3><br/>
                                <field name="termination_contract_date"/>
                                <field name="termination_reason"/>
                                <field name="allocation_cordblood"/>
                                <field name="endstorage_cordblood"/>
                                <field name="allocation_cord"/>
                                <field name="endstorage_cord"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                    </page>
                </page>
                <page string="Internal Notes" position="after">
                    <page string="Parent Details">
                        <group>
                            <group>
                                <h3><label string="Mother Details"/></h3>
                                <br/>
                                <field name="mother_lastname"/>
                                <field name="mother_firstname"/>
                                <field name="mother_dob"/>
                            </group>
                            <group>
                                <h3><label string="Father Details"/></h3>
                                <br/>
                                <field name="father_lastname"/>
                                <field name="father_firstname"/>
                                <field name="father_dob"/>
                            </group>
                            <group>
                                <h3><label string="Child Deatils"/></h3>
                                <br/>
                                <field name="child_lastname"/>
                                <field name="child_firstname"/>
                                <field name="child_dob"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                    </page>
                    <page string="Contact Info">
                        <notebook>
                            <page string="Parent Details">
                                <group>
                                    <group>
                                        <h3>Mother</h3><br/>
                                        <field name="mother_telephone"/>
                                        <field name="mother_mobile"/>
                                        <field name="mother_email"/>
                                        <field name="mother_fax"/>
                                        <field name="mother_fiscalcode"/>
                                        <field name="mother_iban"/>
                                        <field name="mother_bankaccountspain"/>
                                        <field name="mother_decaseddate"/>
                                    </group>
                                    <group>
                                        <h3>Father</h3><br/>
                                        <field name="father_telephone"/>
                                        <field name="father_mobile"/>
                                        <field name="father_email"/>
                                        <field name="father_fax"/>
                                        <field name="father_fiscalcode"/>
                                        <field name="father_iban"/>
                                        <field name="father_bankaccountspain"/>
                                        <field name="father_decaseddate"/>
                                    </group>
                                </group>
                            </page>
                            <page string="Child Details">
                                <group>
                                    <field name="child_telephone"/>
                                    <field name="child_mobile"/>
                                    <field name="child_email"/>
                                    <field name="child_fax"/>
                                    <field name="child_fiscalcode"/>
                                    <field name="child_iban"/>
                                    <field name="child_bankaccountspain"/>
                                    <field name="child_decaseddate"/>
                                </group>
                            </page>
                        </notebook>
                    </page> 
                    </page>
                </page>
            </data>    
        </field>
    </record>

<!-- ========================= Action Layout ============================= -->
    <record id="action_lead" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Lead</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="lead_tree"/>
    </record>
    <record id="create_customer" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Lead</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_res_partner_inherited"/>
    </record>


       <!-- ===========================Menu Settings=========================== -->
    <menuitem name = "Lead" id = "menu_lis_lab" action="action_lead"/>
        <menuitem name="Lead Info" id="sublead_menu" parent="menu_lis_lab"/>
            <menuitem name="Generate Lead" id="generate_leads"  parent="sublead_menu" action="create_customer"/>     
</data>
</openerp>
```

lead.py

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields

class res_partner(osv.osv):
 _inherit = "res.partner"
 _description = "adding fields to res.partner"
 _columns = { 
    'mothername': fields.char('Mother Name',size=64,required=True),
    'fathername': fields.char('Father Name',size=64,required=True),
    'mother_lastname': fields.char('Last name',size=64),
    'mother_firstname': fields.char('First Name',size=64),
    'mother_dob': fields.date('Date of Birth'),
    'father_lastname': fields.char('Last name',size=64),
    'father_firstname': fields.char('First Name',size=64),
    'father_dob': fields.date('Date of Birth'),
    'child_lastname': fields.char('Last name',size=64),
    'child_firstname': fields.char('First name',size=64),
    'child_dob': fields.date('Date of Birth'),
    'storagedetails': fields.selection([('A','21 years')],'Storage Details',help="Storage for no.of years"),
    'insurancecompany': fields.char('Insurance Company',size=64),
    'insurancenumber': fields.char('Insurance No:',size=20),
    'healthfund_name': fields.char('Health Fund Name',size=64),
    'healthfund_number': fields.char('Healt Fund No:',size=20),
    'service': fields.char('Service',size=20,help="Service for no.of years"),
    'annualfee': fields.char('Annual Fee',size=20,help="Annual fee for the service"),
    'paymentplan':fields.char('Payment Plan',size=20,help="Payment plans"),
    'transport_insurance': fields.boolean('Transport Insurance',help="Transport Insurance is taken"),
    'sarm': fields.boolean('Sarm',help="Sarm"),
    'cost_free_donation': fields.boolean('Cost Free Donation',help="Cost Free Donation"),
    'hla_test': fields.boolean('HLA Test',help="HLA Test"),
    'twins': fields.boolean('Twins',help="Are they twins"),
    'repeated_customer': fields.boolean('Repeated Customer',help="Is he repeated customer"),
    'contactadded_date': fields.date('Contact added Date',help="On which date contact has been added"),
    'clientadded_date': fields.date('Client added Date',help="On which day the client is added"),
    'expectedbirth_date': fields.date('Expected Birth Date',help="Expected Date of Delivery for the baby"),
    'bloodrecieved_date': fields.date('Blood Recieved on:',help="When the blood sample is recieved"),
    'bloodstorage_date': fields.date('Blood Stored on:',help="When the blood is stored in Dewar"),
    'cordrecieved_date': fields.date('Cord Recieved on:',help="When the Cord is recieved"),
    'cordstored_date': fields.date('Cord Stored on:',help="When the Cord is stored in Dewar"),
    'termination_contract_date': fields.date('termination_contract_date',help="Your contract  will be terminated on "),
    'termination_reason': fields.char('Termination Reason',size=64,help="Reason for contract Termination"),
    'allocation_cordblood': fields.date('Allocation CordBlood',help="CordBlood is allocated on"),
    'endstorage_cordblood': fields.date('End Storage CordBlood',help="End date of storing of CordBlood is"),
    'allocation_cord': fields.date('Allocation Cord',help="Cord is allocated on"),
    'endstorage_cord': fields.date('End Storage Cord',help="End date of storing of Cord is"),
    'mother_telephone':fields.char('Telephone',size=20),
    'mother_mobile':fields.char('Mobile',size=20),
    'mother_email': fields.char('Email',size=64),
    'mother_fax': fields.char('Fax',size=20),
    'mother_fiscalcode': fields.char('Fiscal Code',size=64),
    'mother_iban': fields.char('IBAN',size=64),
    'mother_bankaccountspain': fields.char('Bank accounts pain',size=64),
    'mother_decaseddate': fields.date('Decased Date'),
    'father_telephone':fields.char('Telephone',size=20),
    'father_mobile':fields.char('Mobile',size=20),
    'father_email': fields.char('Email',size=64),
    'father_fax': fields.char('Fax',size=20),
    'father_fiscalcode': fields.char('Fiscal Code',size=64),
    'father_iban': fields.char('IBAN',size=64),
    'father_bankaccountspain': fields.char('Bank accounts pain',size=64),
    'father_decaseddate': fields.date('Decased Date'),
    'child_telephone':fields.char('Telephone',size=20),
    'child_mobile':fields.char('Mobile',size=20),
    'child_email': fields.char('Email',size=64),
    'child_fax': fields.char('Fax',size=20),
    'child_fiscalcode': fields.char('Fiscal Code',size=64),
    'child_iban': fields.char('IBAN',size=64),
    'child_bankaccountspain': fields.char('Bank accounts pain',size=64),
    'child_decaseddate': fields.date('Decased Date'),
 }
```

Comment: your code seems incomplete. how do you get to know that payment is done?? i mean is there any particular field which defines status of payment??

Comment: What i was planning was i'll have a boolean value as Payment Done.When i do the payment for that particaular customer i'll enable that boolean and then only one can enter the details of Parent Info

Answer (score 1):

If there are different Forms for First Process and Transaction Process, then Create different form for each process and add appropriate fields.

If Single Form with different operations (like state change on button click), then you can show / hide group view.

**[EDIT]**

e.g:

Assign group for Payment fields. and show the group if Payment form is opened. You have to take extra boolean field call "payment_active", which must be invisible in view. and assign 'True' value for Payment form and 'False' for other form.

In Xml:

```
<group string="Payment" attrs="{'invisible':[('payment_active','!=',True)]}">
```

Comment: i'm new to openerp.Can u please share example link

Answer (score 1):

After doing What you have planned. Answer to your question is, to disable fields, put atrrs on that. I will show you an exaple i.e as you have said a boolean field which will show sattus of payment - suppose field that field name is "paid" then, for all those fields which you want disable when payment is not yet done

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('paid', '=', False)]}"
```

to use this on field which you want to invisible, you can use like this

```
<field name="paid"/> <!--here, paid is the boolean field which shows status of payment --> 
<field name="service" attrs="{'invisible': [('paid', '=', False)]}"/>
```

Not only on field, you can also give attrs to entire page like this, (so the page containing all the fields in that will be invisible)

```
<page string="Parent Details" attrs="{'invisible': [('paid', '=', False)]}">
```